# Python tkinter . Le doi a un botón y me aparece una imagen

Tags: python, tkinter, imagen, botón

He empezado a programar hace unos días. Y he empezado por Python.
Me gustaría hacer lo que adjunto en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Código que he podido hacer por mi cuenta:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

root.title("Animales")

root.config(bg="grey")

myFrame=Frame()

myFrame.pack()

myFrame.config(bg="grey")

myFrame.config(width="1000", height="1000")

myFrame.config(bd=5)

myFrame.config(relief="groove")

myFrame.config(cursor="hand2")


botonPez=Button(myFrame, text="Pez",width=8, height=1, font=("Arial", 20))

botonPez.grid(row=0, column=0)

botonLeon=Button(myFrame, text="Leon",width=8, height=1, font=("Arial", 20))

botonLeon.grid(row=0, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Espero que me podáis ayudar y gracias desde ya por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Pero qué quieres hacer?

Comment: Lo explico en la imagen. La edite con el paint. Darle al boton pez y que en el cuadro de abajo me aparezca una imagen por ejemplo de un pez. Y despues darle al boton Leon y que en el cuadro de abajo me aparezca una foto de un leon

Answer (score 0):

Quizás esto pueda servirte:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title("Animales")

root.config(bg="grey")

myFrame = Frame()

myFrame.pack()

myFrame.config(bg="grey")

myFrame.config(width="1000", height="1000")

myFrame.config(bd=5)

myFrame.config(relief="groove")

myFrame.config(cursor="hand2")


def changeImageLeon(imagen):
    path = "ruta_de_la_imagen_del_león"
    img = PhotoImage(file=path)
    imagen.configure(image=img)
    imagen.image = img
    imagen.grid()


def changeImagePez(imagen):
    path = "ruta_de_la_imagen_del_pez"
    img = PhotoImage(file=path)
    imagen.configure(image=img)
    imagen.image = img
    imagen.grid()


imagen = Label(myFrame)

botonPez = Button(myFrame, text="Pez", width=8, height=1, font=("Arial", 20), command=lambda: changeImagePez(imagen))

botonPez.grid(row=0, column=0)

botonLeon = Button(myFrame,
                   text="León",
                   width=8,
                   height=1,
                   font=("Arial", 20),
                   command=lambda: changeImageLeon(imagen))

botonLeon.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Si las imágenes son en `JPG` u otro formato no soportado por `PhotoImage` de `Tkinter`, entonces te recomiendo utilizar `Image` e `ImageTk` de `PIL`.